# Where do I ask Ubuntu questions?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

Just a quick one. Trying not to get voted down on Stack Overflow.

I want to know where on the Stack Exchange communities can I ask Ubuntu-related questions.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what kind of Ubuntu question you have, as asking about programming/developing tools under Ubuntu is fine on SO if it respects the [on-topic subjects](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau The type of question indicated in the comments to Rory's answer definitely would be off-topic on [so].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) Stack Exchange.

Or possibly on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange if the question is a more general Unix/Linux post.

As Jonathan pointed out, if you want to ask about a programming tools under Ubuntu, it's fine to ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

And finally, as Michael said, software questions are on topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Hey - you've got loads of options :-)

Comment: Dangit Rory! (length)

Comment: If he wants to ask about a programming tools under Ubuntu, it's fine to ask on SO. His question is a bit vague on what kind of question he has.

Comment: You could add [su] as well; software questions are on topic there, so by extension Linux questions are as well, so by extension Ubuntu questions are as well. (phew!)

Comment: Basically I am going to ask many "how do you install this, how do you uninstall that". Most of the noob ubuntu questions. That is to say if I cant find the answer first by googling.

Comment: Whesley - in general, you shouldn't need to ask many questions like this. There are a couple of good package management frameworks you can use, or for the more general self compilation ones, there is pretty much a single way to do it. You don't generally need to follow different steps to install different packages (I know - huge simplification)